# Do we really have case in this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble for solving the running time of the following algorithm

[image]

Now first my question, is the case really important here(I can not come up with 2 different inputs of the same size that are different from each other) ?

Second, I think this algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`. Am I right?

Comment: I dont know why this question got -4 points,I even came up with solution and asked just for help

Comment: Because it is a bit off-topic and furthermore you did not show any understanding of the problem. How far did you come? What are your ideas? etc.

Comment: It is simply homework dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you wrote in @OBu's answer is about only a quarter right:
1*n + 2*(n-1) + 3*(n-2) + ... +n*1

That equals to:

Sum(i=1..n, i*(n-i+1)) = n*Sum(i) - Sum(i*i) + n = n*[n(n+1)/2] - [n(n+1)(2n+1)/6] + n

If you want, feel free to compute the exact formula, but the overall complexity is O(n^3).

As a rule of thumb (more like a back-of-the-envelope computation trick I've picked up... just to give you a quick idea): if you are unsure about algorithms with multiple for's (with different lengths, but all in relation with n, as you have above) try to compute how many operations are performed around the middle of the algorithm (n/2). This usually gives you an idea on how the running time complexity for the whole thing might looks like - you are basically computing the largest element in the sum, so the overall complexity is always >= than the thing you compute (in most cases it's the same though).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some hints:

- How many loops do you have and how are they nested?
- How often is each loop running (start solving this from the outer to the inner loop)
- If in doubt, try it with n=4 or 5 and calculate each step. After this, you'll have a good feeling for what's going on.

Comment: Yes I did that Let me explain what I got till now: I tried it with different numbers and I understood that on each iteration of outer loop when the middle loop goes up the inner loop on k goes down so I got this formula: 1*n+2*(n-2)+...+n*(1)=which is n*(1+2+3+....)=n(n+1)/2  but still I am not sure if I am right because usually I get O(n^3) in similar situation and I also my bigger question is do we really need to have case here?